# Serving GeoTIFF files in GeoServer with Image Pyramid Plugin

Tags: image-processing, gis, gdal, geoserver, coordinate-transformation

I have a large set of georeferenced PNG files with PGW world files storing its geospatial info. The images are tiled and should combine into one (there are at least 300000*5000000 of them). Each of these images are around 200MBs in size, so serving them directly in GeoServer as PNGs will take forever to load, which is why I'm choosing to use the Image Pyramid plugin to hopefully speed up the load time.

here is the pgw file:
0.05
0.0
0.0
-0.05
358999.5
5454000.5

This is the process I'm currently going through to do this:

1. First I had to find the lower x and y coordinates of the image, given the image is 10000x10000 pixels (given the upper coordinates are 358999.5 and 5454000.5 as specified in the pgw file) I could find it by:

lower right x = 357499.5 + (10000 * 0.05) = 857499.5
lower right y = 5453500.5 - (10000 * 0.05) = 5408500.5

2. Now with upper left coordinates and lower right coordinates I plug them in to a gdal translate function to convert it into a geotiff file

gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:5836 -a_ullr 357499.5 5453500.5 857499.5 5408500.5 input.png output.tif

3. Then I use gdal_retile to build the tile pyramid of the image

gdal_retile -v -r bilinear -levels 4 -ps 2048 2048 -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=JPEG" -targetDir pyramid output.tif

4. Then I move the generated pyramid folder into the geoserver local data directory, created a ImagePyramid data store and linked it to my newly created pyramid folder then published it.Here is the configurations:
   [image: geoserver config]
5. However the published layer when previewed using openlayers looks like this:

[image]

Anyone have a clue why this isn't working properly?

Thanks

I have tried following the process according to this post: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagepyramid/imagepyramid.html

But it does not display properly.

Comment: there should be no need to specify the bounds in the `gdal_translate` command - that's what the `pgw` file does. It's not clear (to me) where you merge the many PNG files - I would use a `VRT` for that and then build the pyramid from that

Comment: Yea makes sense. I've gotten it to work without the gdal_translate and simply build the pyramids using the pngs and pgw files I have in hand. The gdal_retile worked for me after I removed the -co "COMPRESS=JPEG" flag (it works as in it displays properly in geoserver). Do you know why?

Also, thanks using a VRT makes sense, I will try using gdalbuildvrt() to combine my tiles first then build pyramid from that.